# PDF not previewable with rails active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Following the Rails guide, apparently PDF previews are supported "out of the box" by rails' ActiveStorage.

> some non-image files can be previewed: that is, they can be presented
>   as images. For example, a video file can be previewed by extracting
>   its first frame. Out of the box, Active Storage supports previewing
>   videos and PDF documents.

And the code sample it gives is this:

```
<ul>
  <% @message.files.each do |file| %>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag file.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I uploaded a pdf using this code, and I got this error:

```
ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError
```

Maybe there is something I'm missing?

***Update***

Okay, I think I know what the problem is. I'm supposed to install those third party libraries like muPDF on my machine or on the "Server" for this to work. Running `brew install muPDF` failed for me though. I'll keep researching.

Comment: Worked for me after installing xquartz then muPDF. `brew cask install xquartz` `brew install muPDF`

Answer (score 6):

I may be a little late for you, but for those who still might look for an answer, installing the gem [poppler](https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome/tree/master/poppler) worked for me.

In Gemfile

```
gem 'poppler'
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Now the preview works ! And you can also use file.previewable? to check if the file can be previewed. With the example above :

```
<ul>
  <% @message.files.each do |file| %>
    <%= if file.previewable? %>
      <li>
        <%= image_tag file.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am getting an error "ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError: ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError" any luck?

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma is your file a PDF or a video ?
You can check if your file is previewable with file.previewable?, it will return true if your file is a PDF or a video

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma if you are still struggling with that, the simple solution was to install poppler in system and need to include as gem in the Gemfile as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make my PDF preview work.

I've confirmed the instruction mentioned by @ferne97 on comment worked on my environment.
Namely:

- `brew cask install xquartz`
- `brew install muPDF`

(Apparently, I use MacOS).

Comment: Note `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.  IOW:  `brew install xquartz --cask`

Answer (score 0):

For me on AlmaLinux 8 and with Rails 7, installing the poppler gem to the app did not help.

You need to install `poppler` and `poppler-utils` on system level. For Red Hat family, you can run `yum install poppler poppler-utils`.

You can test pdf preview in rails console. Pick a pdf attachment:

```
attachment = page.uploads.first # or whatever you have
attachment.blob.content_type    # should be "application/pdf"
attachment.representable?       # true, if pdf previews work
```